# Change of Variables Formula for Double Integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

In working on an example of the Change of Variables Formula, I seem to have hit a wall in understanding how to set up an integral. For the following, I have found the correct Jacobian, but am unsure of where I am going wrong on the integration itself.

Let $I = \int\int_D(x^2-y^2)dxdy$

Where $D = {[(x,y):3\leq xy \leq 4, 0 \leq x-y \leq 4, x\geq0, y\geq0]}$

Show that the mapping $u = xy, v = x-y$ maps $D$ to the rectangle $R = [3, 4]$x$[0,4]$

I have found that $\frac {∂(x,y)}{∂(uv)}$ is $\frac1{-x-y}$.

It is when I try to show that $I$ is equal to the integral of $f(u,v)  =v$ over $R$ that I get lost. So far, I have attempted to prove this through a number of trials, however, I cannot seem to quite get the right integral. The following is one of my attempts at it.

$$
\int_0^4\int_3^4x-v\left(\frac1{-x-y}\right)dxdy
$$

Why is it that this integral is incorrect?

Comment: Formatting tip: you can get adjustable-size parentheses, brackets, and so on, by using `\left` and `\right`.  Take a look at how I edited the last integral.

Comment: If you are going to change variables, then you should get an integrand that only involves $u$ and $v$ and you should be integrating with respect to $du\,dv$ or $dv\,du$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you perform the change $u = x-y, v = xy$ , the jacobian is $∂x\,∂y=\frac{1}{x+y}\,∂u\,∂v$.Your new variables $0<u<4\,\,,\,\,3<v<4$ and your integral

$$I = \int\int_D(x^2-y^2)dxdy=\int_0^4u\,du\int_3^4 dv =8$$